# True or False: The sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ is real.

Tags: linear-algebra

True or False: Let $A \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$. The sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ is real.

True, because the sum of the eigenvalues of A is the trace. Since $A$ is defined as a real $n \times n$ matrix, is there any way the sum wont land in the reals?

Comment: The eigenvalues may not be real but the non-real ones appear as conjugate pairs, can you figure out why?

Comment: True. By Vieta formula, the second coefficient of the characteristic polynomial, which is a real, is the sum of the roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what your question about this problem is.  Your answer is correct: the sum of eigenvalues is equal to the trace, which is a sum of real numbers and is therefore real.

As a comment notes, this does not guarantee that the eigenvalues of $A$ are real.